# How do I Double.parseDouble / Float.parseFloat in J++

Tags: j++

Microsoft J++ does not have a Double.parseDouble() method.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String val = "12.45";
double d = new Double(val).doubleValue();
Float f = new Float(val).floatValue();
```